# How do you manage your bash/zsh Aliases?

Tags: bash, zsh, alias

How do you manage your bash/zsh Aliases?

Is there a tool to do this more easily and less "think of an alias -> open .zshrc-sourced-file -> edit -> close, reload .zshrc -> use alias"?

Answer (score 2):

I rarely add or edit my aliases any more, but I still have and occasionally use:

```
alias savealiases='alias > ~/.bash-aliases'
```

I also have `loadaliases`, so I can create or change an alias in one shell (terminal window or tab, tmux window, ssh session, etc) and easily load it into other running shells.

```
alias loadaliases='source ~/.bash-aliases'
```

To make sure my aliases are loaded when I login or start up a new shell, I have the following in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
[ -e ~/.bash-aliases ] && . ~/.bash-aliases
```

Extremely primitive but it's worked well enough for me for over 20 years.  If I need to do any fancy editing of my aliases, I have vi.

Comment: Note: In Zsh you need to use ```alias -L``` to get them in sourcable format.  My trusty ```sa```-alias is always the first thing I create in a new account. Surprised it is not more common.

Comment: @JoachimLous thanks for the zsh -L comment.  And, yeah, this was a pretty common (and commonly recommended) thing to do back in the 90s.   I prefer the long forms, savealiases and loadaliases, because I use them so infrequently and don't want to waste valuable 2 or 3 letter command names on them or conflict with other programs. It's also easy to remember: "I want to save my aliases, what's that command called again?" :-)

Answer (score -2):

If you are not only interested in bash and zsh, you may be interested in a completely different method that was introduced by the UNOS command interpreter in 1980. This command interpreter implements persistent aliases that are stored in the file `$HOME/.globals`

This method is now available in bsh and in recent Bourne Shell version you may get from the Schily-Tools.

Please have a look at the recent Bourne Shell man page at:

http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html

The reason why I mention this method is that complex alises in the Korn Shell syntax are hard to type with the correct quoting and the Bourne Shell implements (as an additional method besides `alias`) so called hash commands that allow to enter aliases in raw mode.

BTW: the correct way to save aliases for other shells that do not support persistent aliases is:

`alias -p > file`

If you just call `alias` with ksh93, you get output like this:

`autoload='typeset -fu'
 command='command '
 compound='typeset -C'`

but when you call `alias -p`, you get:

`alias autoload='typeset -fu'
 alias command='command '
 alias compound='typeset -C'`

As you see, you need `alias -p` because it returns something that can later be used as shell input again by calling:

`. file`

Edit: `alias -p` is not POSIX but no shell except bash seems to produce parsable output by default. Some shells never produce parsable output!

Shells that need `-p` for a `parsable`output are:

- Bourne Shell
- ksh93 (ksh88 does neither support parsable output nor -p)

bash permits -p...

BTW: **dash** does not support parsable output nor -p at all.
**zsh** implements the equivalent of `alias -p`via `alias -L`.

Comment: AFAICS, there's no mention of `alias -p` in the [POSIX specification for `alias`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/alias.html), and in practice is only supported in ksh, bash and yash. The question is about `bash` (where `alias` works the same as `alias -p` except in sh emulation, and it's true that in that case `alias -p` would be needed) and `zsh` (where `-p` is not a supported option).

Comment: OK, I edited my text, but I do not have "yash".

Comment: In `zsh`, you use `alias -L`. The POSIX output of `alias` is parsable, but not POSIXly. For instance in `bash` or `zsh`. `eval "a=($(alias))"` would work. Also note that `zsh` has the different types of alias definitions in associative arrays (`$aliases`, `$galiases`...).

Comment: POSIXly, you could use `xargs` to process the output of `dash`'s `alias`, but not that of `ksh93` which uses the `$'...'` form of quoting in some cases.

Comment: `yash` is at http://yash.osdn.jp/index.html.en

Comment: Not very convincing. this is what I get on a POSIX2001 certified system: config.status: Syntaxfehler in Zeile 109: `dir=$' unerwartet
WARNING: yash is designed for systems that conform to POSIX.1-2001
         but your system does not

Comment: Like it says. On Solaris 10, `getconf _POSIX_VERSION` returns `199506` which is what I complains about. You'd also need to put yourself in a POSIX environment.

Comment: If it is really POSIX, it should know that it should call `/usr/xpg6/bin/getconf`.

Comment: Or, you should call that script where that `getconf` is first in `$PATH`. The premise here is that the environment must be a POSIX.1-2001 compliant one.

Comment: Then it should not compile on Linux ;-)